# Get Attribute ID using Element name

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to retrieve the attribute ID using the Element name. unable to do it.

```
<root> 
    <child Id="001">Hello</child>
</root>
```

Example : when we pass the value `Hello` it needs to provide the attribute ID as `002`

Anyone please help me to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide and example and or code sample of what you are currently working with..it's very difficult to determine what you are talking about based on this question, when you say pass the value `Hello` what do you mean as well as how are you passing it? show your code as well

Comment: Should `Hello` return `001` ??

Comment: Can you show us a code example of anything you've tried?

Comment: also based on your `XML` how can you ever return `Attribute id of 002 <child Id="001">Hello</child>`

Answer (score 1):

What version of the .NET framework do you have access to? If you can use Linq to XML retrieving an attribute name should be very easy.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("path to your xml");
XElement element = document.Descendants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "element name");
var attribute = element.Attribute("Id");
```

(Pseudo code, can't guarantee it works exactly as I don't have time to compile this right now but that's the general idea)

Here's a quick example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387086.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Using System.Xml.Linq;

string xml = @"<root><child Id=""001"">Hello</child></root>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var itemName = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Value == "Hello")
    .Attribute("Id").Value;
```

Comment: The Where clause seems unnecessary as FirstOrDefault provides a predicate by which you could filter for the element's value

Answer (score 0):

Linq + XPath can work here very well.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var id = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(String.Format("//*[text()='{0}']", "Hello"))
              .Attribute("Id").Value;
```